# How to configure routes to have "/username" and "/group-name" in the url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

How do you configure routes and controllers to have the following in Rails? I want paths that can point to a user by it's username or to a group by it's name.

/username and /groupname for example instead of /user/name and /group/name. It's obvious that users and groups can't share names. I also would like to have /username/about, /groupname/posts, and any other arbitrary path which is not common between the two models.

I also generated a model and table to link names and objects and IDs. Also how would you build the controller here. Can you help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In my opinion, it isn't a good idea to mix the logic of groups and users. Why do you want to do a thing like that and not go for routes like `/user/name` and `/group/name`?

Comment: i dont think the logic of your app should dictate the urls ;) if he wants pretty urls, y not? nevertheless it's not that simple. you could use an extra model along with a polymorphic association.

Comment: I just saw that it works like this on facebook, and liked the idea. It's just a way to shorten URLs :)

Comment: May be putting match '/:username', :to => "users#show" at the end of the routes.rb

and in the User controller if user with that name is not found redirect to groups#show

Comment: Unfortunately Rails doens't have nice ways to redirect to another controller/action. Sure, we have redirect_to, but that would issue a new HTTP request, and the URL would be altered after all :(

Answer (score 0):

Why not have the controller look up the name and pick the appropriate logic path based on the result (e.g., `/name` routes to `#show`, which calls `show_user()` for a username, and `show_group()` for a groupname)?